# Как добавить точку в цикле for in range?

Tags: python, циклы

Вот код:

```
a = (input("Напишите слово:"))

for i in range(1, 10+1): 
  print(i + ".", a)
```

Выдаёт ошибку: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Пробовал так же добавить **int** и **str**, но не работает

```
a = (input("Напишите слово:"))

for i in range(1, 10+1):
  print(int(str(i + ".", a)))
```

Нужно чтобы выдавало вот так:

```
1.
2.
3.
```

И так далее...

Comment: `print(str(i) + ".", a)` или даже `print(f"{i}. {a}")
`

Comment: Надо пробовать не бездумно, а со смыслом, хотя бы пытаясь понять, что происходит. Что это ``int(str(i + ".", a))``? Сначала переводишь в строку сумму числа и точки, хотя тебе уже сказали, что число и точку сложить нельзя. Потом пытаешься строку с точкой перевести в целое число. Зачем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = (input("Напишите слово:"))

for i in range(1, 10+1): 
  print(str(i) + ".", a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно через f-строки.

Так:

```py
a = input("Напишите слово:")

for i in range(1, 10+1): 
    print(f'{i}.', a)
```

Или так (как писали в комментариях):

```py
a = input("Напишите слово:")

for i in range(1, 10+1): 
    print(f'{i}. a')
```

Подробнее в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals).

Answer (score 1):

```
a = input("Напишите слово:")

for i in range(1, 10 + 1):
  print(i, ". ", a, sep = '')
```

Почитай как использовать функцию Print() в Python.